# EditText right drawable doesn't update after showError

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-appcompat, android-textinputedittext

`EditText` right `drawable` doesn't update after `showError` method gets called. I have tried to set `setError` to `null`, set right `drawable` to `null` but nothing helps.

```
Drawable right = DrawableUtils.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.eye_look);
right.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, rigth.getIntrinsicWidth(), right.getIntrinsicHeight()));
myEditText.setError(null, null);
myEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(DrawableUtils.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.pass_look), null, right, null);
```

Any ideas ?

Code example for checking:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    vEditText.error = "Some error"
    vButton.setOnClickListener {
        vEditText.error = null
    }

    vEditText.setOnTouchListener(object : OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(p0: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            val DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0
            val DRAWABLE_TOP = 1
            val DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2
            val DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3

            if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (event.rawX >= (vEditText.right - vEditText.compoundDrawables[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].bounds.width())) {
                    vEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, ContextCompat.getDrawable(vEditText.context,android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on), null)
                    vEditText.error = null
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    })
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please put your code here?

Comment: Hello, just updated

Comment: Also add your layout xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myEditText.setError(null);
myEditText.setErrorEnabled(false);
myEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.icon), null, ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.icon), null);
```

Comment: I need EditText not TextInputLayout

Answer (score 0):

First decorate the `EditText` with your desired `Drawable`.

```
Drawable right = DrawableUtils.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.eye_look);
right.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, rigth.getIntrinsicWidth(), right.getIntrinsicHeight()));
myEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(DrawableUtils.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.pass_look), null, right, null);

...
```

Now whenever need to show error just use

```
myEditText.setError("Your error message");
```

And hide error drawable like below

```
myEditText.setError(null);
```

Which actually hide the error drawable and show your drawable. No need to do anything more.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have update your code, check now

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //This is important to set here
    vEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, ContextCompat.getDrawable(vEditText.context,android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on), null)

    vEditText.error = "Some error"
    vButton.setOnClickListener {
        vEditText.error = null
    }
}
```

Now type something on `vEditText` or click `vButton` and check.

Comment: @salut-amigo, Check my answer and let me update. Thanks

Comment: Does not work... I have updated the question and set code example

Comment: I have update your code in my post. Try and let me know

Comment: I need to change the right drawable icon in vEditText.setOnTouchListener from android:drawable/btn_star_big_off to android:drawable/btn_star_big_on